# Array conditions placeholder substitution problem (Rails3 Active Record)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Could anyone please tell why this code  won't work:

```
scope :scope_a, lambda {|x, y| select('DISTINCT ?', x).order('? ASC', y)}
```

(says ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)), whereas this

```
scope :scope_b, lambda {|x, y| where(:cond1 => x).where(:cond2 => y)}
```

works perfectly?

How does one construct a proper scope with conditions like the 1st example (when seemingly it's impossible to use hash conditions)?

**UPD** The safe solution turned out to be trivial:

```
scope :myscope, lambda{|field, mode| {:select => field, :conditions => {:moderated => mode}, :order => field}}
```

..but doesn't this way of setting scope conditions get deprecated (not sure) in future RoR versions?

Answer (score 1):

The approach you're taking only works for the `where(...)` method, not for `select(...)` (which is what's throwing the error) or for `order(...)`.

You'll probably want to do this (since an `order` clause will default to be ascending, you can just pass in `y` directly):

```
scope :scope_a, lambda {|x, y| select("DISTINCT #{x}").order(y)}
```